# How to save files using django form wizard?

Tags: django, django-formwizard

How to save files using django form wizard? I use Django 1.3 and i can't find examples and solutions. ;-/

With google and django docs i wrote this:

```
class ContactWizard(FormWizard):

def done(self, request, form_list):
    d = dict((k, v) for form in form_list for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items())
    d['ip'] = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    d['password'] = hashlib.sha1(d['password'])
    db = Ads(**d)
    db.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

OK, this save all POST data. But files? I can catch them using request.FILES. I have to save them separately? How to do it best? My form with files is last step in form wizard.
I will be grateful for suggestions and examples ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just passing it to Ads as a [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField)? So basically, something like this:

```
d['myfile'] = request.FILES['myfile']
```

Comment: Why haven't i thought about it? Simple solution. It works. Thanks.

Comment: The request holds the files of the last form only. Any suggestion for retrieving files from previous forms?