# Binding Files to Form Django Wizard

Tags: django, forms, wizard

So I was [unsuccessful at hooking up the Session-based wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693811/django-formwizard-as-view-method-attributeerror) from django-merlin, but I am trying again with the wizard that is included in the django source. However, when trying to upload files using `ImageField`, it seems that the files `request.FILES` are not being bound to the form, because after trying to upload a file I get a "This Field is Required" error. Here is what I have:

forms.py:

```
class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES)
    ...

class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
    main_image = forms.ImageField()
    ...

class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        d['main_image'] = request.FILES['main_image']
        db = Thing(**d)
        db.save()
        return render(request, 'wizard-done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

In the `CreateWizard` above I have tried to save the `main_image` in the `done` method as was [discussed in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860529/how-to-save-files-using-django-form-wizard), but I have not been successful.

---

UPDATE:

Adding `enctype=multipart/form-data` has allowed me to bind the file, but now I am getting a new error:

```
global name 'request' is not defined
```

even though the request context processor is in my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. Defining the done method like in the linked stackoverflow post did not work either:

```
class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
    def done(self, request, form_list):
```

results in a `TypeError: done expects 3 arguments, 2 given`

Answer (score 2):

You will need `self.request`:

```
return render(self.request, 'wizard-done.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],  })
```